# Sideband on HP ILO2 and initial in-OS setup possible?

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant, console, ilo

Is it possible to configure sideband (ILO being physically accessed from one of the main NICs as opposed to the dedicated ILO NIC) for the ILO2?

Also is it possible to configure the ILO2 initially from inside the OS (Server 03... don't laugh lol)?  I am more familiar with Dell OpenManage.  Even if you never configured the DRAC and set up its IPs you can install OpenManage and access it through http_s://localhost:OM_PORT_HERE/.  The clunky ILO2 configuration utility seems to want you to point it to a server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes...

ILO can be configured to use a dedicated port *or* as a shared ILO, with the first Ethernet port. Note, you won't be able to ping the ILO from within the OS when in shared-mode.

You can also configure an ILO from within a running operating system using the `hponcfg` utility. This allows you to retrieve an XML configuration from the device, modify and reapply it.

Either way, you will want to bring the firmware of the server and all components up to date. Please download the massive [HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD (HP SPP)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018#!tab=features) to do this.

Comment: So if I set to shared mode I won't be able to access the ILO, even from HPONCFG?  or do you just mean ping it?  It seems to hook into it through a hardware driver, not the network.

Comment: @asdfdasfasdfgasdf Just ping. I said nothing about hponcfg.

Comment: @asdfdasfasdfgasdf Did this work for you?